# Displaying the Error Messages in Laravel after being Redirected from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**How can I display the validation message in the view that is being redirected in Laravel ?**

Here is my function in a Controller

```
public function registeruser()
{
    $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
    $lastname = Input::get('lastname');
    $data  =  Input::except(array('_token')) ;
    $rule  =  array(
                'firstname'       => 'required',
                'lastname'         => 'required',
                   ) ;
    $validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Register Failed');
    }
    else
    {
    DB::insert('insert into user (firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)',
                                array($firstname, $lastname));
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Register Success');
    }
    }
```

I know the below given code is a bad try, But how can I fix it and what am 
 I missing

```
@if($errors->has())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

### Update : And how do I display the error messages near to the particular fields

Comment: You have to return the error messages, something like `return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator);`

Comment: @SA__ How you holded the typed value in each field after the validation redirect ?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

**Laravel 4**

When the validation fails return back with the validation errors.

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

You can catch the error on your view using

```
@if($errors->any())
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif
```

**UPDATE**

To display error under each field you can do like this.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
@if($errors->has('firstname'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</div>
@endif
```

For better display style with css.

You can refer to the docs [here.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#error-messages-and-views)

**UPDATE 2**

To display all errors at once

```
@if($errors->any())
    {!! implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) !!}
@endif
```

To display error under each field.

```
@error('firstname')
    <div class="error">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="firstname">  how can i hold the typed value after validation ?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') }}">` or use form helper, it will automatically hold the value after validation error.

Comment: Note that `$errors->first('firstname')` will only display the first message for the given field. You may have multiple errors; get them as an array for looping over like this: `$errors->get('firstname')`

Comment: For people using bootstrap, here's your code snippet:   @if($errors->any())
      {!! implode('', $errors->all('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">:message</div>')) !!}
  @endif

Answer (score 39):

If you want to load the view from the same controller you are on:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return self::index($request)->withErrors($validator->errors());
}
```

And if you want to quickly display all errors but have a bit more control:

```
 @if ($errors->any())
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <div>{{$error}}</div>
     @endforeach
 @endif
```

Answer (score 11):

```
@if ($errors->has('category'))
    <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('category') }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: Please provide some details.

Comment: Please provide additional detail in your answer to summaries what your code does.

Answer (score 8):

A New Laravel Blade Error Directive comes to **Laravel 5.8.13**

```
// Before
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
@endif

// After:
@error('email')
    <span>{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 7):

to Make it look nice you can use little bootstrap help

```
@if(count($errors) > 0 )
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="p-0 m-0" style="list-style: none;">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.  For example, why does this work ?

Answer (score 5):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required', ]);

if ($validator->fails()) { return $validator->errors(); }
```

Comment: Great you are helping, can you please explain for the less experienced fellows why and how your code solves the problem.
To make the post more concise and readable use the proper formatting stackoverflow suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5):

You can use like below to print with html tags :

```
@if($errors->any())
    {!! implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) !!}
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Below input field I include additional view:

```
@include('input-errors', ['inputName' => 'inputName']) #For your case it would be 'email'
```

input-errors.blade.php

```
@foreach ($errors->get($inputName) as $message)
    <span class="input-error">{{ $message }}</span>
@endforeach
```

CSS - adds red color to the message.

```
.input-error {
    color: #ff5555;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving All Error Messages For All Fields

To retrieve an array of all messages for all fields, use the all method:

```
foreach ($errors->all() as $message) {
    //
}
```

Laravel 9,
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#retrieving-all-error-messages-for-all-fields

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it's nice to see a good first answer here, I upvoted your answer but please consider adding a link to the api documentation for this specific method and note which version of Laravel you're using.

Answer (score 0):

## This is also good way to accomplish task.

```
@if($errors->any())
  {!! implode('', $errors->all('<div class="alert alert-danger">:message</div>')) !!}
@endif
```

We can format tag as per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) use the following to show the error with floating message

```
@if($errors->any()) 
     <script type="text/javascript">
         toastr.error({{ implode(' ', $errors->all()) }});
    </script> 
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using Laravel 8 and Bootstrap 5, you can display the errors neatly with alerts doing it like this:

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
        <strong>
            {!! implode('<br/>', $errors->all('<span>:message</span>')) !!}
        </strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{!! Form::text('firstname', null !!}

@if($errors->has('firstname')) 
    {{ $errors->first('firstname') }} 
@endif
```

Comment: I think you should explain why you suggest this solution. It tells nothing as it is.

Answer (score -4):

Move all that in kernel.php if just the above method didn't work for you
remember you have to move all those lines in kernel.php in addition to the above solution

let me first display the way it is there in the file already..

```
protected $middleware = [

    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

now what you have to do is

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
     \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [

    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

i.e.;

[image]

Comment: Doing this would make all those middlewares active for all of your current routes, instead just add the "web" middleware group to your routes. Like so Route::get('/home', 'controller@home')->middleware('web'); or add it into your controllers __construct method like so: $this->middleware('web'); If you are running a recent version of laravel,   the 'web' middleware group is automatically applied to your routes/web.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.