# Laravel: Resource controller 'store' method produces no results, no errors

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I'm trying to implement the category creation form on the backend of a site I'm building. The idea is to have it be on the same page as the index of existing categories. At present, though, the creation system does nothing. It doesn't return an error; nothing shows up in the database when queried directly; and nothing new appears on the page as per the redirect. Because there's no feedback, I'm groping around for what's different/wrong about this route versus the very similar route I made for the post creation mechanism earlier. In any case, here's the relevant creation form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('categories.store') }}" data-parsley-validate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="name">Category Name:</label>
          <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required maxlength="255">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
```

Here is the 'store' method from the CategoryController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
          'name' => 'required|max:255'
        ));

        $category = new Category;
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Category has been created!');

        return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }
```

And here is the web.php routes file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'PageController@getIndex');
Route::get('/contact', 'PageController@getContact');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
Route::get('blog/{slug}', 'PostController@show')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
Route::get('blog', 'PostController@index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

?>
```

Again, I'm not getting any error messages at all, it's just that the submission button does nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return redirect('categories.index')->withErrors($validation);
```

you can also check this

[Display errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732821/displaying-the-error-messages-in-laravel-after-being-redirected-from-controller)

Comment: other thing to try is wrap the whole thing in a try catch.

Comment: The above as well as the recommended link had no effect. RE: the recommendation of a try-catch statement, I'm assuming the idea is to wrap the whole of the current store action in the try clause?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error myself. At the top of the view in question, there is a table for displaying the existing categories. The closing  tag was missing its forward slash which I overlooked. Apparently this entirely interrupted the functionality of the form that came later without throwing any errors.

**The moral of the story is:** If you are working with dynamic behavior on a web app and not getting any exceptions, there is a chance it's because the error is in your HTML.