# errors message laravel not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have some error in my validate data, the errors message not show in my blade file.Maybe you can help me

This is my code

> tambah_jamaah.blade.php

```
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'jamaah.store']) !!}
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            Error :<br />
            <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li></li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
        @endif
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              {!! Form::label('Name', 'Nama Jamaah') !!}
              {!! Form::text('Name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
            'placeholder' => 'Masukan Nama Jamaah ...']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {!! Form::label('Number', 'Nomor Telepon') !!}
              {!! Form::number('Number', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
              'placeholder' => 'Masukan Nomor Telepon ...']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {!! Form::label('Birth', 'Tanggal Lahir') !!}
              {!! Form::date('Birth', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {!! Form::label('Wa', 'Nomor Whatsapp') !!}
              {!! Form::number('Wa', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
               'placeholder' => 'Masukan Nomor Whatsapp (Opsional) ...']) 
             !!}
            </div>
              </div>


              <div class="box-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
              </div>
               {!! Form::close() !!}
```

> JamaahsController.php (store method)

This is my code in JamaahsController@store

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Validasi data
    $this->validate($request, [
            'Name'      => 'required|max:255',
            'Number'    => 'required',
            'Birth'     => 'required'
        ]);

    $pbk = new Pbk;
    $pbk->Name   = $request->Name;
    $pbk->Number = $request->Number;
    $pbk->Birth  = $request->Birth;

    $pbk->save();
    return redirect()->route('jamaah.index');
}
```

Im not sure by adding some group(middleware) in my routes

> routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
Route::resource('jamaah', 'JamaahsController');
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your blade file code like :

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: @AzzarioRazy Ok let me check it

Comment: @AzzarioRazy Please follow this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732821/displaying-the-error-messages-in-laravel-after-being-redirected-from-controller) May be help for you

Comment: @AzzarioRazy Also u can create custom validation message using request file

Answer (score 0):

Official document recommends this code for validation errors. Right now you do not display any errors in your li items.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

For debugging I also suggest adding this code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       
    //Validasi data
    $this->validate($request, [
            'Name'      => 'required|max:255',
            'Number'    => 'required',
            'Birth'     => 'required'
        ]);
    dd($request->all());
```

If dd outputs anything, then validation does not fail at all.

If validation fails then in your blade try this code. After posting with dd() in controller and then refresh the post without dd() in controller so you will see errors in blade.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'jamaah.store']) !!}
{{dd($errors)}}
```

This shows you whats inside the $errors and if there are any errors found.

Comment: ViewErrorBag {#166 ▼
  #bags: []
} <- the result

Comment: This means that at this moment there was now errors. 
Try to make the testing procedure as
1. remove validation and add dd() in controller method
2. make post call and see the dd output from controller
3. add back validation and add dd() in your blade
4. refresh the page to submit same invalid data again with validation to get validation errors and see what is in the bag