# Display Laravel Validation Errors?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm new to Laravel,
here I'm working with Laravel project. I need to display validation errors in form

```
<div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 input-field">
            <input name="newpassword" id="newpassword" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="newpassword"> New Password </label>
            <small class="email_error"><div class="error">@error('newpassword'){{$message}}@enderror</div></small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'newpassword' => 'required|min:8',
], [
    'newpassword.required' => 'New Password is required field.',
    'newpassword.min:8'    => 'Enter Minimum 8 Characters',
]);
```

errors :

[image]

Comment: and what is your question? you have a JSON response, everything seems to be in working order, you just have to do something with that response

Comment: Please can you show the javascript you're using to submit the form.

Comment: return back()->with('error', 'You have entered wrong password'); @Rwd

Comment: That isn't javascript. If you're getting a json response, I'm assuming you're using some sort of ajax to submit the form?

Comment: Thanks Bro, because i found my error, i'm use both method ajax or without ajax in one form, i forget to stop ajax @Rwd

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to make a shared blade file, which you can use for any error handling (sessions, requests & etc..). The file would look something like this:

```
@if ( session()->has('success') )
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="alert text-white" style="background-color: #47afc4;     border-radius:5px;">
                {!! session('success') !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
@if ( session()->has('error') )
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {!! session('error') !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

The `session()->has('success')` would catch any success session messages that you return in you controller:

```
return redirect('your route')->with('success', 'Success message');
```

The `session()->has('error')` would catch any error session messages that you return in you controller:

```
return redirect('your route')->with('error', 'Error message');
```

And `$errors->all()` will return any errors from the request validation.

You can then use this file in the pages you want, simply include it:

```
@inlcude('path.to.shared.errors.file')
```

If you need any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$errors->any()` function

To find your answer look at this :

[Displaying the Error Messages in Laravel after being Redirected from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732821/displaying-the-error-messages-in-laravel-after-being-redirected-from-controller)