# In Laravel, how to tell validation errors due to user input from errors due to the application?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Suppose I have this `store` method in a controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
   $request->validate([
      'first_name' => 'required|string|alpha',
      'last_name' => 'required|string|alpha',
   ]);
   // Create user
}
```

Now let's say I receive this data from the frontend:

```
{
    "first_name": ["John"],
    "last_name": "Mac_Donald"
}
```

For some reason, the frontend wrapped the first name input by the user in an array, so it's an error due to the application; as for the last name, the user accidentally added an underscore, so it's an error due to the user (let's pretend client-side validation wasn't in place).

In this scenario, Laravel responds with this 422 error:

```
{
    "message": "The first name must be a string. (and 2 more errors)",
    "errors": {
        "first_name": [
            "The first name must be a string.",
            "The first name must only contain letters."
        ],
        "last_name": [
            "The last name must only contain letters."
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I tell errors due to bad user input from errors due to application errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying the Error Messages in Laravel after being Redirected from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732821/displaying-the-error-messages-in-laravel-after-being-redirected-from-controller)

Comment: rather than bad user input, this is an issue of bad frontend/backend code. If first name can be an array, it must always be so, and validated as such. If first name must be string, it must never be an array in front end.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of how you handle the application errors. Usually laravel returns a 422 status code if there's a problem with validation.But if the problem is from application it returns a 500 status code with the exception message, name of exception and stack trace.

```
try {
    $books = Book::query()->create($request->validated()); // Let's say I have a unique constraints in my table but I didn't validate it before storing. It will throw a QueryException
} catch (Throwable $th) {
    // You can customize the response that the application will return if there's an error

    // You can throw a ValidationException
    throw ValidationException(['key' => 'value']); // It will return a 422 status code and a json same with the example you give.

    // You can also return a response instead of throwing an exception
    return response()->json([
        'key' => 'error message'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Like I showed in the example in my question, the problem is exactly that, in the case of validation, Laravel returns a 422 error both for user errors and application errors. If first_name is of the wrong type (application error), it returns a 422 error, not a 500 error.

Comment: if the user is the wrong type, it's not passing the validation .... so it's a validation error.